# Do stacked boxes get stored in the workbench?

Tags: fallout-4

I've noticed in Fallout 4 while building settlements sometimes you will encounter stacked boxes. Often when you decide to scrap the bottommost box in the stack, all of the boxes stacked above it will disappear.

I'm wondering if these boxes which automatically disappear get stored in the workbench automatically, or if they disappear entirely? When I'm scrapping boxes and want to get all of the resources, do I need to scrap each box individually, or can I save time by just scrapping the box at the bottom of the stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once did a little test in-game to see whether or not it were the case, and had to conclude **the parts of these stacked boxes are not broken down when the bottom one is scrapped first**.
This doesn't only apply to stacked boxes, but everything that's stacked and scrappable.

Comment: Oh wow, so you've got to scrap each item individually? That seems like a design oversight